# memcached vs memcache

Tags: memcached

Прошу прощения за, возможно, очевидный вопрос, но я только начал смотреть в сторону этих инструментов. Знаю только что один старый, а другой новый. Может ли уважаемое сообщество объяснить разницу между этими инструментами и их сферы применения?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Продукта, под названием «memcache», AFAIK, не существует.

Есть «[memcached](http://www.memcached.org/)» (быстрое key-value хранилище в памяти), и есть «[MemcacheDB](http://memcachedb.org/)» (использует протокол memcached, но хранит данные, если правильно помню, в BerkeleyDB, обеспечивая персистентность). Ну и еще есть всякие, использующие протокол все того же memcached, [Membase](http://www.couchbase.org/get/couchbase/current) сотоварищи, с кластеризацией, репликацией и прочими плюшками.

Догадаюсь откуда растут ноги. У PHP есть два клиента, как раз, зовущихся один «[memcache](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.memcache.php)», а другой — «[memcached](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.memcached.php)». Собственно, есть [таблица со сравнением](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/PHPClientComparison) этих двух клиентов, по ней, думаю, все должно быть понятно.

pecl/memcachepecl/memcached

Первый релиз2004-06-082009-01-29 (beta)
Внешние зависимостиНетlibmemcached
Автоисправление ключа¹ДаНет
Добавление в начало/конецНетYes
Автоматическая сериализацияДаДа
Бинарный протоколНетОпционально
CASНетДа
СжатиеДаДа
ТаймаутыТолько на подключниеРазличные опции
Консистентное хэшированиеДаДа
Отложенный GETНетДа
GET нескольких значений за запросДаДа
Поддержка сессий PHPДаДа
SET/GET на указанный серверНетДа
Хранение чиселПреобразуются в строкиДа

¹) При попытке SET или GET на некорректный ключ, memcache преобразует некорректный ключ в корректный, а вернет `false`.

Comment: Да, именно о двух клиентах идет речь.

Comment: Ок. Тогда добавил таблицу со сравнением в ответ. Если что-то простое — memcache прекрасно подойдет для большой части задач, а если нужно сложнее (и есть libmemcached) — memcached более наворочен.